# How to call a VBScript file in a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-2.0, vbscript

I need to call a [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) file (.vbs file extension) in my C# Windows application.
How can I do this?

There is an add-in to access a VBScript file 
in Visual Studio. 
But I need to access the script in code behind. How to do this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The following code will execute a VBScript script with no prompts or errors and no shell logo.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cscript //B //Nologo c:\scripts\vbscript.vbs");
```

A more complex technique would be to use:

```
Process scriptProc = new Process();
scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"cscript"; 
scriptProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\scripts\"; //<---very important 
scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments ="//B //Nologo vbscript.vbs";
scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //prevent console window from popping up
scriptProc.Start();
scriptProc.WaitForExit(); // <-- Optional if you want program running until your script exit
scriptProc.Close();
```

Using the `StartInfo` properties will give you quite granular access to the process settings.

You need to use [Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) if you want windows, etc. to be displayed by the script program. You could also try just executing `cscript` directly but on some systems it will just launch the editor :)

Comment: Will the program calling System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() hang until the process ends, or will it continue on leaving the process to run in the background?

Comment: Yes. By default the program will run without waiting for the process to end. However, System.Diagnostics.Process.Start().WaitForExit() will force the calling program to wait for the process to end.

Comment: I think the filename  has to be the file name. i.e not cscript

Comment: Can I pragmatically add "permissions to execute" as well?

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to create a VB.NET Class Library project, copy your VBScript code into a VB.NET Class file, and reference the VB.NET Class Library from your C# program.

You will need to fix-up any differences between VBScript and VB.NET (should be few).

The advantage here, is that you will run the code in-process.

Comment: However, I did use the method from @Ilya above - this was an excellent way for me to test that my vbscript and vb.net code was producing the same results.

Answer (score 4):

This is a permissions issue.  Your application appPool must be running at the highest permission level to do this in 2008. The Identity must be Administrator.

Answer (score 3):

You mean you try to run a vbs file from C#?

It can be done like [running any other program from C# code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(VS.80).aspx):

```
Process.Start(path);
```

But you have to make sure that it won't ask for anything, and it is running with the command line version of the interpreter:

```
Process.Start("cscript path\\to\\script.vbs");
```

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of searchers, I found this [post](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f5505d3-ab39-4f66-9ce5-95a7af432d22/passing-a-parameter-from-a-c-form-to-a-vbscript-and-executing-script?forum=Offtopic), which gives a clear answer (esp if you have parameters). Have tested it - seems to work fine.

```
string scriptName = "myScript.vbs"; // full path to script
int abc = 2;
string name = "Serrgggio";

ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
ps.FileName = "cscript.exe";
ps.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", scriptName, abc, name);
//This will equate to running via the command line:
// > cscript.exe "myScript.vbs" "2" "Serrgggio"
Process.Start(ps);
```