# Which scripting language should be used for automating .net build

Tags: .net, build, clearcase, cruisecontrol.net

I want to know which scripting language can be used for to make automated .net build through cruise control and clear case.

.net has references which needs to be mentioned while building.

I am using cruise control integrated with clear case.

Answer (score 0):

Considering CruiseControl can call about any script you want, you can use:

- perl (and call cleartool command from there: see "[How can I interact with ClearCase from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273200/how-can-i-interact-with-clearcase-from-perl/2273896#2273896)")
- or CAL (and use C# programs or VB scripts, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739000/clearcase-checking-in-and-out-using-c-sharp/6739459#6739459))
- a NANT script, using the `exec` task in order to call cleartool.
  See "[`NAnt -> Help -> Task Reference -> <exec>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html)" page.

NAnt example:

```
<exec program="cmd" commandline="/c cd /path/to/view" />
<exec program="cleartool" commandline="yourClearToolCommand" />
```

Those scripts will be triggered by one of the [ClearCase triggers](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#clearcase) integrated with CruiseControl.

Comment: Can NANT scripts can be used ?

Comment: @user1383839 If NANT script can make system call (in order to call `cleartool`, and to read the stdout and stderr of a system command), then yes.

Comment: @user1383839 I just added an NANT (very small) example

Answer (score 0):

Although CC does support many build engines, http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/, but none of them are quite popular in .NET world.

If you are using CruiseControl (not CruiseControl .NET), there is no built in support for MSBuild, and you have to use `<exec>` to launch MSBuild.exe from .NET Framework installation folder, (one hop)

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#exec

Or you can call NAnt from CC, and use the  task in NAnt to execute MSBuild for project compilation. (two hops then)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample NANT script which have will use .net reference while build

Comment: Nope. You don't need to use .NET reference in NAnt. Simply call <msbuild> task to invoke MSBuild.exe, who reads sln/csproj/vbproj files to perform the compilation, such as http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc4/help/tasks/msbuild.html