# Running a program through complete address VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i am trying to run a .vbs script that is not in the same directory as the program is in

```
Dim CustomInstalaionPath As String = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test"
Process.Start(CustomInstalationPath + "/run.vbs")
```

the program is running in the normal directory for de-bugging

C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects...

i have tried loads of ways but nothing is successfully running it

any help would be awesome
thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Exception?  Message box?  Motherboard on fire?

Comment: It doesn't matter that it is in a different directory. What error are you getting? Also, when concatenating strings, you should use &, not +.

Comment: its all fixed now thanks anyway

Comment: @reblerebel: Please edit your question to specify exactly what wasn't working.  Was the script not working correctly?  Was it running, but operating on the wrong directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [the version of `Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) that takes a `ProcessStartInfo` structure.

This will allow you to [set the `WorkingDirectory` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx), which is what you're looking for.

Something like:

```
Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process 

p.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "//B //Nologo C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\myfile.vbs"
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test"

p.Start(p.StartInfo)
```

Also see this question (for C# that uses the same class).  If you check it out, make sure to add the `WorkingDirectory` property:

- [How to call a VBScript file in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application)

Comment: it's written in VB.NET but i have found a way to do it

Comment: @reblerebel: Did the VB.Net code I provide here not solve the problem for you?  If this code helped you, make sure to accept the answer.

Comment: Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
        ProcessProperties.FileName = "notepad"
        ProcessProperties.Arguments = "blaaa.txt"
        ProcessProperties.WorkingDirectory = "C:/"
        ProcessProperties.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
        Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(ProcessProperties) that what i used

Comment: it didnt help but thanks anyway

Comment: @reblerebel: You can add your own answer and accept it too.  Helpful for people in the future.

Comment: i did try and it said that i couldnt for 8 hours then forgot ill post it now

Comment: @reblerebel: Probably can't until it gets reopened.  I guess the question was decided not to be clear enough to understand by enough people that it got closed by a mod.

Comment: i will edit your comment and pop it at the bottom