# Running a vbs with process.start as another user avoiding UAC

Tags: c#, vbscript, passwords, process.start

I'm trying to run a vb script using process.start() as another user that have admin rights, but i always get the UAC popup with username and password to fill. What i'm i doing wrong?

```
var scriptProc = new Process
                    {
                        StartInfo =
                            {
                                FileName = @"cscript,
                                WorkingDirectory = @"\\AShare\AFolder",
                                Arguments = "\"" + "Install.vbs" + "\"",
                                UseShellExecute = false,
                                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                                Domain = domain,
                                UserName = username, //Admin username
                                Password = MakeSecureString(secureString),
                            }
                    };
scriptProc.Start();
```

I want the UAC to popup with yes and no options and not with username and password to fillout options.

tried looking at: [How to call a VBScript file in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application) but that didn't help.

Comment: This smells like a virus. What is this for?

Comment: I'm developing a little applications so when you click on a icon, it installs a program, depending on which icon you click on, from a local server with username and password provided by my IT Service Team. Not making a virus here :) I did something before where the UAC popup didn't show, then I changed something in the startInfo and now the UAC popup shows x|

Comment: The UAC will always popup for programs that do things that require elevation. End of story.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear in my question. It's okay that the UAC always popup and you can click yes or no, but what happens is that the UAC pops up with username and password for the user to fillout. In my code I've added UserName and Password in StartInfo to think that it will avoid that you have to type the username and password but still get the UAC to popup with yes/no options.

Comment: It will be much easier for you running your application without the prompt if you already know the user's password.

Comment: I know the username and password but i can't figure out how to implement it to my application. Is it possible to make my application startup as a different user instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, in Windows 7 even admin accounts run with standard user rights. Take a look at this [TechNet article by Mark Russinovich](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx)

From above article.

> When UAC is enabled, all user accounts—including administrative accounts—run with standard user rights. This means that application developers must consider the fact that their software won't have administrative rights by default. This should remind them to design their application to work with standard user rights. If the application or parts of its functionality require administrative rights, it can leverage the elevation mechanism to enable the user to unlock that functionality.

---

Edit:
What you are talking about is user impersonation:

You can look at some of these articles

1. [WindowsIndentity Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e599ywa6.aspx)
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051/Windows-Impersonation-using-C
4. [Windows Impersonation from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp)
5. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158
6. http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic62740.aspx

Comment: I tried #2 article and it worked like i wanted to :) Thank you very much!