# Can I run vb script from C# application ?

Tags: asp.net

Can I run vb script from C# application.Can anybody provide me vb script with exam
like on button click show message,if perticular panel is visible.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can run vb script code inside c# code, but this [How to call a VBScript file in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application)
could do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute VBScript directly in the same C# process, but you *can* execute it through a separate process using the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

```
Process.Start("path to vbscript", "arguments if any");
```

---

If you are talking about *client side* on a browser, then this can only work on IE (the only browser that supports vbscript).

Comment: I am new to vb script.Can u plaese provide me the entire example?

Comment: @JuiTest - I don't know what you are trying to achieve - your question is very unclear in that respect.

Comment: Can u tell me how to call vb script file from C#?

Comment: @JuiTest - I did. Again, not clear what you are trying to do.