# Invoking clearcase compare with previous version window using c#

Tags: c#, clearcase, clearcase-automation

I want to compare the clearcase file with its previous version programmatically in C#.

Is there any way to invoke clearcase comparison window using C# CAL libraries for a file?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote and the flag: it is a perfectly valid programming question.

Comment: Sorry for the closed question. You have hundreds questions similar to this one on stack Overflow, but those "moderators" are clueless.

Comment: That is perfectly fine VonC. You have given me the appropriate answer and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as illustrated in "[How to call a VBScript file in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application)", it is best to wrap the cleartool diff call in a VB script and call that script from your C# program.

That would allow for your VB script to call a cleartool command, with the command `diff --graphical` in it (which will open the diff windows)

```
ClearCase.ClearTool CT = new ClearCase.ClearTool();
string result;
result = CT.CmdExec("diff --graphical ...");
```

---

The [OP Ramesh K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294722/ramesh-k) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990577/invoking-clearcase-compare-with-previous-version-window-using-c-sharp#comment19392468_13990859):

> The above `CmdExec` worked for me. I used:

```
 ct.CmdExec("diff -graphical -pre "+filePath);
```

> directly in C# application and it invokes the graphical interface of the ClearCase diff tool.

Comment: Dear VonC, thanks a lot. The above CmdExec worked for me. I used ct.CmdExec("diff -graphical -pre "+filePath); directly in C# application and it invokes the graphical interface of clearcase diff tool.