# How to correctly run VB script using c# in Sharepoint 2013, subnet scan

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint-2013, subnet

Im using Sharepoint 2013 .Net 4.5 and I need run VB script in code behind(C#).
This script should scanning my subnet and save new xml with devices in subnet.
The script runs and xml file is created but inside I don't have any devices.
When I run this script in cmd is ok.

This is my c# code:

```
    string scriptName = "audit_subnet.vbs";
    string create_file = "create_file=y";
    string submit_online = "submit_online=n";
    string subnet = "subnet=" + StartIP.Text + "-" + EndIP.Text;
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"cscript";
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\xml";
    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\"", scriptName,create_file, submit_online, subnet);
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
      exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
```

In debug:

```
   startInfo.Arguments = "\"audit_subnet.vbs\" \"create_file=y\" \"submit_online=n\" \"subnet=10.70.77.1-10.70.77.1\""
```

Here is this script(example):
https://github.com/ethanhann/open-awesome/blob/master/bin/audit_subnet.vbs

I changed the script myself and it works when I run it in cmd.

Why when I start this script in c# is created file but won't scan subnet?

Comment: similiar question to SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application.. so, to be clear.. the vbscript is not executing? Is it possbily a permission issue, are you giving the Application the rights to execute the file?

Comment: if you are looking for a vbscript answer, best to use that tag rather than vb.net

Comment: Brett Caswell,
My vbscript is executing but he dont scan subnet.
exeProcess.WaitForExit(); is waiting for end and script is ending. Script is creating new file in folder but in file I dont have and devices.
When I executing script in cmd in new file I have more nodes with devices. It is xml file.

Comment: I think it is a problem with permission but I don't know what permissions to give?