# Run VBScript from C# with hidden window and capture output

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am able to run VBScript from C# and capture standard output and error streams using this code:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\scripts\";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "//B //Nologo vbscript.vbs";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
...
```

This works fine but shows a console window. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200429/3658668), I can set process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden to hide the console window. I found that this only works if I don't capture the console output, i.e. if I comment out these lines:

```
//process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
//process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
//process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Is there any way I can hide the console window and still be able to capture the output from the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add 1 more line:

```
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't realize there was another parameter for hiding the window.