# Is it possible to use my VB program in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a module in VB like this

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        /* some piece of code here */
    End Sub

End Module
```

And I want to execute its `Main` from a project in C# because both the languages comes under `.net` so is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So, what have you tried and where's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a VBScript file in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application)

Comment: VB what? `VB6`, `VB.NET`, `VBA` ... something else? If its not managed did you make it COM visible? Have you tried *anything* at all?

Answer (score 0):

### Add reference

Build it as a DLL, put Public in front of some thing slike this

```
Public Module Module1
 ... Public sub Main
```

and add the dll as a reference to the c# project. **DONE.**

### <s>But the VB app is an EXE and this is the startup sub!</s>

You can't use it like that.

### I guess you can!

see amy's comment. I swear I tried it at one point ... and failed... sorry about that.

Comment: You can add a reference to an executable, and you can call `main`.  It's just a function.

Answer (score 0):

a VB.Net Module is a C# Static Class.
so, if you reference the VB.Net Project or Vb.Net Compiled Assembly, you can call Main sub routine in this way:

```
Module1.Main();
```

but to do that, Module1 and Main must be marked as public:

```
Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        /* ..... */
    End Sub

End Module
```