how can i run a vb script string in vb.net (or other languages)?
I'm looking for a way to run raw vb script code as String in VB.NET (not in a .vbs file!).
Is it possible?
If not, is there any other language in which i can? (my possibilities are node.js, python, any C# framework, java)
More context: i have a windows service using vbscript. It's running raw vbscript i send to it. I need to replace thiswith something else than vbscript but it wiil still receive vbscript and need to run it. It doesn't necessarily have to be a windows service, that's why i can use almost any language possible. The onely must is to be able to run any raw vbscript i send to it.
I tried searching on google but found nothing

Does this answer your question? Dynamic code execution: String -> Runtime code VB.net

You could safe the script to a file and use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application

i know i could use a file, but i'm looking for a way to not use a file.

VBScript was replaced by Powershell almost 20 years ago. You can host Powershell in any .NET application. You can't run VBScript with VB.NET, they're different languages despite the somewhat similar syntax. A lot of the things that required COM objects in VBScript are now available as built-in classes, including files and regular expressions.

Try this in Google site:stackoverflow.com vb.net run vbscript and you’ll see this question has been answered many times already.

Thx. Most of the answers are to run a vbs file

You can add a script control to your .net code to make your application scriptable. Note that your vbscript will execute in an isolated space and will not see the objects of your main .net code unless you explicitely makes your objects visible through ScriptControl.AddObject()
Having a web service that receives vbscript code and executes it seems like a big security hole. At a minimum, I recommend setting the ScriptControl.UseSafeSubset property to True.
Dim ScriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
ScriptControl.Language = "vbscript"
ScriptControl.Timeout = -1
Try
    ScriptControl.AddCode(YourVBSCodeAsText)
Catch
    Console.WriteLine(ScriptControl.Error.Source & ": " & ScriptControl.Error.Description & " (" & ScriptControl.Error.Line & ", " & ScriptControl.Error.Column & ") ")
End Try

